# Why doesn't the world help Israel fight against Hamas?

Tags: military, israel, gaza

in the last two days Israel has been in "Operation Wall Guard". In the crisis that caused this "operation", Hamas has launched more than a thousand rockets towards Israeli cities.

I am well-aware that Hamas has mixed with the Gaza Strip's citizens, while Israel wants to strike down Hamas officials and rocket launchers.

Israel - to the best of my knowledge - tries to minimize as much as possible the harm done to the Gaza Strip's civilians, but Hamas' targets - to the best of my knowledge - are Israeli civilians.

Why doesn't the world protect Israel? Or more particularly, why doesn't the world help Israel fight against Hamas (while minimizing damage to civilians, of course)? I have seen a lot of criticism from other countries on Israel's actions, but nobody (that I know of) really recognized the need for protection from the side of Israel. How is this possible? What is causing other countries to "stay out" of this conflict?

Comment: I see that you have accepted my answer. It is common here to wait a couple of days, to see if a better one comes around. I also notice four close votes on your posting, probably be people who think that your question goes too far into *advocacy of a cause.* Still, you should un-accept and wait.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @o.m. , I will do so :)

Comment: In re "nobody really recognized the need for protection from the side of Israel"... that's almost certainly not the case. I'm pretty sure US administrations (both D & R) did that, at least formally, and some European governments probably did that as well, but I don't have the time to look for quotes on that angle now.

Comment: Just in the latest confrontation "Blinken says Israel has an “absolute” right to defend itself and its citizens from militant attacks but that it must take all possible steps to protect innocent Palestinians." https://www.myrtlebeachonline.com/news/article251347003.html Even Hollande in 2014 said something like that https://www.reuters.com/article/us-palestinians-israel-france-idUSKBN0FF2CV20140710

Comment: @Fizz, Germany subsidized submarines for Israel and just about everybody believes that they will be nuclear-armed. That's not "neutral" ...

Comment: You might want to reword this question to make it seem less like your trying to push your opinion (I’m not saying you are, I’m saying it seems like it) to get it re-opened. I edited it to try and do this

Comment: Im obviously biased since I live in Israel, so thanks for the edit!

Comment: What specific political cause is this question supposed to promote or discredit such that people voted to close it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several partial answers to this.

- Israel **does** get aid, mostly from the United States. But you are right that it does not get the overwhelming support of the rest of the world.
- Israel does not *appear* to be the underdog in need of aid. There are usually many more dead Palestinians than Israelis. The pictures and perceptions influence how governments react (contrast US aid during the Yom Kippur war).
- There are people in Europe who think that Israel has overreached in their attempt to secure defensible borders, and therefore bears a significant part of the blame for the mess it is in. The [BDS Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boycott,_Divestment_and_Sanctions) gets some popular support.
  Even people critical of BDS find it hard to *justify* the Israeli settlement policy, except for some part of the [US evangelicals](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2018/05/14/half-of-evangelicals-support-israel-because-they-believe-it-is-important-for-fulfilling-end-times-prophecy/).

Answer (score 4):

Additionally (to o.m's answer), Hamas is already under sanctions from both the US, and I think to a lesser extent [by the EU](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2019/3/6/eu-court-upholds-freeze-on-hamas-funds) as well. Short of militarily overthrowing Hamas (i.e. "regime change" in Gaza), it's not clear the world could do that they aren't doing already. And Israel probably already has the means to do that (regime change) it's probably that they don't find the cost worth the trouble (i.e. another occupation of Gaza).